# Read all Lines on file using relative path

Tags: c#, file-io, nullreferenceexception, relative-path, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a project in c# .Net Razor MVC5 and I would like to read a file and push lines into a List.

```
List<string> file = new List<string>();
string path;
int rand = _rand.Next(0, 5);
string fileName = _listfileName[rand];

path = "~/Content/file/" + fileName + ".txt";
try
{
    path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("cant load the file: " + e.Message);
}
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path);
file = lines.ToList<string>();
```

I have an exception on **File.ReadLines(path)**:

> *A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in MyProject.dll cant load the file: Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.*

I don't know why I have this problem. I didn't found any solution on stackoverflow.

Could someone know the problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a custom VirtualPathProvider? It's probably throwing an exception on the path you're trying to give it. Is the path valid? What fileName have you tried it with?

Comment: Because the it catch an exception on HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path), I verified the path. I also verified that my solution include the file. I think the problem is comming from the line "HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);" But I don't know why

Comment: I don't have any VirtualPathProvider, I don't really know what it is

Comment: I have another line exception just after : "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: Where do you have this code? It's possible that HttpContext.Current or HttpContext.Current.Server is null. For example, HttpContext.Current can be null inside asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Yeah, that's to be expected - you passed it an invalid path, so DirectoryNotFoundException is obviously the right exception to get :)

Comment: I verified on the debug, and yes the Current is null (cf: Edit image)

Comment: Beware thread safety issues using a static Random.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the server path without using HttpContext.Current?

Comment: Okay, now, where (and when) are you actually calling this method? There are some cases in which you simply don't have access to a HttpContext - asynchronous operations, and I think that since IIS Integrated mode, you can't access it in HttpModule constructors and some other places. Maybe you could at least post the call stack of the exception?

Comment: Oh, yeah - `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`. I'm just asking for more information because you're probably doing something wrong along the way :)

Comment: this method is called by a signalR hub static method

Comment: The HostingEnvironment.MapPath is working ! Thank you so much Luaan <3